# Adicionar quantidade de gold para jogador

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Eu tenho um servidor de [ Mu Online ] Ex 802 , e o mesmo possui sistema de { SHOP CASH } para os jogadores poderem comprar seus itens. Bom o meu Servidor tem um painel de controle na qual posso adicionar a quantidade de moeda que o Player terá , mais esse sistema é em C#.

O Shop Cash jogo usa 1 tabela para se conectar com  o sql:

```
     - Tabela " GameShop_Data"
     - Colunas " MemberGuid , WCoinC , WCoinP , WCoinG"
```

Ele faz essa verificação: Quando entra no jogo, e abre o Shop Cash, existe um campo chamado :  { Quantidade de Golds: VALOR } 
    - Basicamente a verificação para saber qts golds tem ele faz o seguinte: ELE BUSCA NO SQL a TABLE "GameShop_Data" ( como o usuário conectou com a conta dele ele já tem como base o member_guid ) então ele busca na tabela o campo MemberGuid do usuário conectado e la tem a coluna " WCoinC " ( sendo a moeda principal ) e ve a quantidade de Golds nesta coluna e mostra la no JOGO a quantidade que verificou no SQL.

- As colunas que começa com W são os tipos de moeda que tem no JOGO.
- A coluna MemberGuid é como se fosse um tipo de " id " de organização.

Porem o Servidor tem um site na qual existe 3 tipos de painel de controle:

- Painel de Controle do Usuário
- Painel de Controle do Game Master
- Painel de Controle do Administrador
- No painel de controle do { administrador } tem a opção de adicionar a quantidade de moeda , nele existe dois tipos de moedas.
- Para adicionar precisa basicamente de três campos { login , nome da moeda ( SELECT sendo duas ) , quantidade }.

Mais se eu colocar somente o login como identificação , não funcionará.

Pelos simples motivo:

> INSERT INTO "GameShop_Data" ("username","WCoinC", ...) VALUES ("usuário digitado no input", "VALOR digitado no input",);

Se executar este código , irá aparecer um " id " aleatório no banco de dados.

> > Um exemplo: Se o usuário que eu quero colocar gold , tem um id de numero 25 , mais na tabela existe 3 usuários colocados , ou seja vamos supor que esses três eu coloquei os ' Golds ' através do painel que eu citei la em cima primeiro feito no C#.

[ MemberGuid ]    |    [ WCoinC ]    |    [WCoinP]    |    [WCoinP]

```
 "1"                  "500"            "NULL"           "NULL"
 "2"                  "500"            "NULL"           "NULL"
 "3"                  "500"            "NULL"           "NULL"
```

" O SCRIPT EXECUTADO PELO PAINEL FEITO NO C# ESTÁ FUNCIONANDO CORRETAMENTE "

Mais se eu executar o script acima com dados em especifico tendo em base que esse usuário que eu digitei no campo do input do Painel de Controle do WEB SITE o id é " 6 "

> INSERT INTO "GameShop_Data" ("username","WCoinC",) VALUES ("mauricio1", "1000",);

A TABELA FICARIA ASSIM:

[ MemberGuid ]   |   [ WCoinC ]   |   [WCoinP]   |   [WCoinP]   | [username]

```
  "1"              "500"           "NULL"         "NULL"       "NULL"
  "2"              "500"           "NULL"         "NULL"       "NULL"
  "3"              "500"           "NULL"         "NULL"       "NULL"
  "4"              "1000"          "NULL"         "NULL"       "mauricio1"
```

> > Ou seja: ele criou um MemberGuid aleatório por si tratar de um " int " com chave primary ( e não colocou o id " 6" que no jogo identificaria os 'Golds' da conta logada ).

Bom eu gostaria de saber qual script devo ultilizar para fazer essa verificação corretamente e assim poder adicionar os Golds para os jogadores atráves do Painel de Controle do WEBSITE.

- Lembrando que o id do login de cada conta fica na tabela " MEMB_INFO " como na segunda imagem da publicação.

[image: TABELA GameShop_Data]

[image: TABELA MEMB_INFO]

Comment: Porque o banco deveria ter salvo o id `6` se você não o colocou em nenhum lugar. Acredito, se entendi a pergunta, que a sua query seria assim: `INSERT INTO "GameShop_Data" ("MemberGuid","username","WCoinC",) VALUES (6, "mauricio1", "1000");`. Outra coisa, tente simplificar sua pergunta, deixe apenas o necessário para entender o problema e você terá mais pessoas tentando te ajudar.

Comment: Olá Oeslei. Obrigado pela resposta. Bom vamos la, se eu executar essa query que você mencionou em cima iria criar um id tendo como sequencia o anterior: Pois nesse momento na tabela " GameShop_Cash " existem 3 contas editadas com os Golds ' colocada a partir do painel feito em C# ' ou seja, se eu executasse esse SCRIPT acima, iria criar o próximo ID ' que seria o 4 ' e não o id '6' correto da conta , na qual o jogo verifica.

Comment: Oeslei tem razão. Dá pra minificar bastante sua pergunta, além de aumentar as chances de uma resposta precisa, facilitaria o entendimento e agilizaria a coisa toda. Tenta remover o que não é essencial ao assunto.

Comment: @Junior conseguiu resolver seu problema?